# Strange Database Questions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
(
    cid CHAR(4), 
    cname CHAR(20), 
    PRIMARY KEY(cid)
)

CREATE TABLE orders 
(
    oid CHAR(6), 
    odate CHAR(6), 
    custid CHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY(oid), 
    FOREIGN KEY (cusitd) REFERENCES customers(cid) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

If number of customers records be 10 and number of order records be 15, after the running of following commands,

```
DELETE FROM customers C  
WHERE C.cid = '2000'
```

The sum of all records in customers and orders tables at least and at most is equal to:

- at most 24- at least 9
- at most 25- at least 9
- at most 24- at least 18
- at most 25- at least 18

Our TA select (2). Why ? it's strange question :) without knowing the table !

Comment: It's best not to use `CHAR` in Oracle - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2)  at most 25- at least 9

The sum of all records beforore delete is 10+15 = 25.
In case when there is no customer with C.cid='2000', the delete command does not delete any records, and the sum stays the same ==> at most 25 records.
In case when the customer C.cid='2000' exists, and all records in orders table are referenced by customer C.cid='2000', then the delete commands deletes one record from customers table, and all records from orders table (15), in total 16 records.
25 - 16 = 9, so at least 9 records.